# How to replace special characters from CSV headers before loading to MySQL using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I usually work with large datasets and am trying to code a script which will load the dataset without much manual work (I work for non-tech company). The script will run another test while loading the data(but i have not proceeded to write that part of the code yet). I was able to load the data using the below code:

```
mycursor.execute("drop table if exists  rd.data")
with open(r"C:\Users\rcsid\Documents\Office Programs\Working prog\MOCK_DATA.csv") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'''create table rd.data ( {" varchar(100), ".join(row)} varchar(100))''')
            sql_str=f'''create table rd.data ( {" varchar(100), ".join(row)} varchar(100))'''
            mycursor.execute(sql_str)
        sql_str1=f'''insert into rd.data values ('{"',' ".join(row.values())}')'''
        print(sql_str1)
        mycursor.execute(sql_str1)
        line_count += 1
```

The code will load the data without needing to update the code manually(the %s technique, which I don't think my colleagues will be able to code). So, I have solved the first part of the problem. The problem I'm running into now is if the csv headers have special characters in them. I want to replace the special characters with '_'. I was able to research a bit and come up with the following update:

```
mycursor.execute("drop table if exists  rd.data")
with open(r"C:\Users\rcsid\Documents\Office Programs\Working prog\MOCK_DATA.csv") as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            #print(f'''create table rd.data ( {" varchar(100), ".join(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]\n\.', '_', row))} varchar(100))''')
            sql_str=f'''create table rd.data ( {" varchar(100), ".join(re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]\n\.', '_', row))} varchar(100))'''
            mycursor.execute(sql_str)
        sql_str1=f'''insert into rd.data values ('{"',' ".join(row.values())}')'''
        print(sql_str1)
        mycursor.execute(sql_str1)
        line_count += 1
```

Now if i include the `'[^a-zA-Z0-9]\n\.'` with the `\n\.` then the error is :

```
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash
```

If i remove it then the error is :

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Can someone help me with the two above problems and how to replace the special characters and create the table. I'm new to Python therefore it may seem very basic. P.S: The data is used for analysis only and not loaded to any server or anything.

Comment: To help simplify, have a look at `pandas.read_csv` and `pandas.to_sql`.  As can be inferred from the function names, these functions can be used to read the CSV data; (along with any character replacements), then stored to SQL; with the database table being created automatically if you wish.

Comment: Regarding the regex pattern place an `r` before the string as: `r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]\n\.'`. This tells Python to use a *raw* string and prevents from interpreting the backslashes as escape characters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I replaced the regex with your code: print(f'''create table rd.data ( {" varchar(100), ".join(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]\n\.', '_', row))} varchar(100))''') but still getting the f-string error mentioned above. Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue with the following code:

```
mycursor.execute("drop table if exists  rd.data")
#r"C:\Users\rcsid\Documents\Office Programs\Working prog\MOCK_DATA.csv"
#re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]\n\.', '_', row)
reader = csv.DictReader(open(r"C:\Users\rcsid\Documents\Office Programs\Working prog\MOCK_DATA.csv",encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore'), delimiter=',')
rowHeaders = reader.fieldnames
print(rowHeaders)
for i in rowHeaders:
    field_name.append(re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '_', i))
print(field_name)
print(f'''create table rd.data ( {" varchar(100), ".join(field_name)} varchar(100))''')
sql_str=f'''create table rd.data ( {" varchar(100), ".join(field_name)} varchar(100))'''
mycursor.execute(sql_str)
for row in reader:
    sql_str1=f'''insert into rd.data values ('{"',' ".join(row.values())}')'''
    print(sql_str1)
    mycursor.execute(sql_str1)
```

Do let me know if this has any back draws.